# Why does the Calendar (GregorianCalendar)'s time change by 12 hours when setting the Hours and Minutes, after midnight, as opposed to before midnight

Tags: java, android, time, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm Creating a Calendar of type GregorianCalendar and setting it to my timezone (GMT+12)
Then I literally set the time from strings for hour and minute eg "06" "37"
Then display the time in ms
If I do this with the device time set before midnight
The timeinms then equates to 6:37PM , should be AM

However, if I do this after midnight 
the timeinms equates to 6:37AM, which is correct

My Code is as follows

```
public Calendar getTime (Location Loc, String definition)
{


    Calendar event = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("NZ"));

  int DD = event.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  int MM = event.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
  int YY = event.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String HH="";
    String mm="";

String CivilSunrise ="06:37"

if (definition=="sunrise"){
        HH = CivilSunrise.substring(0,2); // 06
        mm = CivilSunrise.substring(3,5); // 37
    }

    if (definition=="sunset"){
        HH = CivilSunset.substring(0,2);
        mm = CivilSunset.substring(3,5);
    }

    Long before = event.getTimeInMillis(); 

    event.set(Calendar.HOUR,Integer.parseInt(HH));
    event.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(mm));

    Long after = event.getTimeInMillis();


return event;

}
```

Why is this happening, obviously the date changes after midnight but surely the time added to the Calendar object by string should be the number of hours from midnight

```
time backwards to wed 6th may 23:41

23:53 sunrise     output millis: Wed May 06 18:37:37 GMT+12:00 2020
23:52:46.661     output hours 2020-05-06T06:37:37.631Z

23:55 sunset      output millis: Thu May 07 05:54:57 GMT+12:00 2020
                  output hours 2020-05-06T17:54:57.284Z
the output for millis is incorrect, the output for hours is correct

Now I set the android time Forwards to 1:00AM 7/5/2020

sunrise      output millis: Thu May 07 06:38:46 GMT+12:00 2020
             output hours 2020-05-06T18:38:46.737Z

sunset       output millis: Thu May 07 17:53:24 GMT+12:00 2020
             output hours2020-05-07T05:53:24.384Z
```

now the output for millis is correct, the output for hours is incorrect
 the logs are produced with

```
Log.d("sun","output millis: " + event.getTime());
    Log.d("sun","output hours" + event.getTime().toInstant());
```

Comment: By the way, `NZ` is not a real time zone name. Use `Pacific/Auckland` for New Zealand.

Comment: Never use `Calendar`. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. For Android < 26, use *ThreeTenABP* back-port. `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ).with( LocalTime.of( 6 , 37 ).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`